# Python adding files from URL to file on local file

Tags: python-3.x, io, python-requests

I am trying to combine two files from the internet, and save the output on my computer. I have the below code,but no made what I try I always get the same result. I get the first URL, and nothing more.
To be exact, I am trying to comebine VideoURL and videoURL1, together into one file called output.mp4...

```
videoURL= 'http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4'
videoURL1 = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'
# print(str(embeddHTMLString).find('sources: ['))

local_filename = videoURL.split('/')[-1]
# NOTE the stream=True parameter

response = urlopen(videoURL)

response1 = urlopen(videoURL1)

with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = response.read(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        f.write(chunk)
with open(local_filename, 'ab+') as d:
    while True:
        chunk1 = response1.read(1024)
        if not chunk1:
            break
        d.write(chunk1)
```

Comment: A proper way is to download 2 mp4 files to local and concat into a single mp4 file. You cannot “combine” them with append.

Comment: So your saying there is no way to get the files, and then turn them into chunks, and then add them to one file in bytes? I find that hard to believe... I may be speaking out of ignornance, and not knowing how chunks of bytes work...

Comment: The problem is not on how chunks and bytes works. Media files contains format header and metadata, combining 2 media files into 1 meant you need to rewrite new metadata and format header, and remove the old ones. You will need the help with ffmpeg / mp4box to do this job for you.

Comment: oh i c, thank you i will mark this as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. The gist of this answer has already been given by @Tempo810, **you need to download the files separately and concatenate them into a single file later**.

I am assuming you have both `video1.mp4` and `video2.mp4` downloaded from your urls separately. Now to combine them, you simply cannot use append to concat the files, since video files contains format header and metadata, and combining two media files into one means you need to rewrite new metadata and format header, and remove the old ones.

Instead you can use the the library [`moviepy`](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy) to save yourself. Here is a small sample of code how to utilise `moviepy`'s `concatenate_videoclips()` to concat the files:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
# opening the clips
clip1 = VideoFileClip("video1.mp4")
clip3 = VideoFileClip("video2.mp4")
# lets concat them up
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2])
final_clip.write_videofile("output.mp4")
```

Your resulting combined file is `output.mp4`. Thats it!